# Excel: Automatic replacement of text in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of possible heights that I want to replace with a whole number, for example when a person types 4'11" in a cell, I want it to become 411.

I'm having a problem with the quotation mark. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an adjacent cell, you can input this array formula to extract only the numbers from the text string.

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IFERROR((MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),1)*1),""))
```

This is an array formula, so press CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER in the formula.

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That is perfect

Answer (score 0):

SUppose data is in Column A, in text form A2=4'11", A3=5'07", A4=4'09"

In Cell B2 enter the formula : B2=LEFT(A2,1)&MID(A2,3,2)

Copy the formula down B3:B100

Thanks.